# I need my system to acquire a system current time

Tags: php, mysql

My system, developed in PHP and MySQL, has two HTML fields named `Time_in` and `Time_out`.

I want both of these fields to acquire a system current time.

What code would you suggest?

Below is a line of code for insert some fields and the `Time_in , Time_out` fields too.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES ('$BID', '$Route', '$Driver_Name',
                 '$Driver_phone_no', '$Time_in', '$Time_out', '$Date' , '$Comment')";
```

Comment: Are you escaping your SQL variables? Otherwise this code is VERY vulnerable (SPECIALLY if `$tbl_name` is from the user).

Comment: If this is the only code you use to set these values then they will always be the same - this makes no sense!

Answer (score 5):

Use [**NOW()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) to get the current date and time.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) to set the current timestamp, or set up an [insert trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) (and possibly and update trigger also) so that you don't need to remember to explicitly set the values for those two fields.

Be careful though, if you need to "massage" data in a table with such triggers set up and you don't want all rows to be updated to a new time_in/time_out value.

Here's an example of a table and triggers being created. A row is then inserted into that table and shortly afterwards updated. Notice that even though the UPDATE only explicitly updates the comment, the time_out value is also changed.

```
mysql> create table tableName (`id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment, `route` varchar(50), `driver_name` varchar(50), `comment` blob default '', `time_in` timestamp , `time_out` timestamp , primary key(`id`)) engine=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.07 sec)

mysql> create trigger tableName_bInsert BEFORE INSERT on tableName for each row set new.time_in=NOW();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> create trigger tableName_bUpdate BEFORE UPDATE on tableName for each row set new.time_out=NOW();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> insert into tableName set route="Belfast-Tralee", driver_name="Ken", comment="Pick up dogs. In.";
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tableName;
+----+----------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | route          | driver_name | comment           | time_in             | time_out            |
+----+----------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Belfast-Tralee | Ken         | Pick up dogs. In. | 2013-12-17 13:51:13 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----+----------------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update tableName set comment="Dogs - out" where id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from tableName;
+----+----------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | route          | driver_name | comment    | time_in             | time_out            |
+----+----------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Belfast-Tralee | Ken         | Dogs - out | 2013-12-17 13:51:37 | 2013-12-17 13:51:37 |
+----+----------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```